# Spring call to https backend - handshake issue

Tags: spring, security, ssl-certificate, handshake

I'm struggling with a problem recently.

I have to make an HTTP call to a secured backend using SPRING restTemplate !

It works smoothly for http endpoint but for an https it gives me the following error:

**sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target**

I have already resolved this issue before importin the certificate to the cacerts in the jre/security of the JDK.

It would be best for me finding a way not to do this thing for every machine i deploy my .war on.

Any clues ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're using SSL you're always going to have to put the certificate on any machine serving up the WAR - only way around it would be a "beefy" machine/hardware running multiple instances of JBoss with all of them pointed at the same keystore

Comment: Are you using a self signed server cert or a client cert or something?